# Table not displaying all rows in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table

I'm working with a txt file in ArcGIS. When I display the table and scroll down it seems to encounter an error and won't display any records past about 10,400. There are roughly 200,000 records.

It then gives me the error:

> Could not load data from the data source. If you can correct the
>   problem, press the refresh button to reload data. Possible problems
>   can include bad network connection, invalid field, etc.

The txt file is on my computer so it's not a network connection. Any thoughts?

Comment: Possibly there are invalid characters in the file. What is the structure of the text file? Is it a CSV? What type of encoding? How did you load the data into ArcGIS? Have you investigated the text file in a text editor or Excel? Do you see anything on row 10,400 that looks suspicious?

Comment: I frequently experience problems with CSV files in ArcGIS; it's usually not ArcGIS that's at fault, like @Fezter says there's probably an invalid character. I import the files into a personal geodatabase with Microsoft Access as it's better at handling bad rows, from there it's easy to use in ArcGIS. Note: if you don't have Microsoft Access an .XLS is less buggy than a CSV generally; open office will *save as* these formats if you don't have Microsoft Office.